# deploy ABP framwork angular into iis

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, abp

I want to deploy ABP angular  Application into IIS I don't know how.

I created a folder contain the backEnd Folder And The FrntEnd Folder then i build the frontend into the frontend Folder and in the visual studio, I publish the backend into the backEnd Folder

in IIS I created a website with the backEnd with HTTPS and inside the Website I created a App contain the frantEnd
the App works and the data appears in the list

but in create and update method not function

[image]

I look inside the log [image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't changed the application settings.

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.DbMigrator/appsettings.json

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.HttpApi.HostWithIds/appsettings.json

You need to change application ports, URL. etc

Comment: i did change the application port into https://localhost:44376 44376 for the backend and the frantend   and i'm able to get the list  but in crud method  (create,update,.....) i get error of 405 and 400